# Search bar with ListView possible in Flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, searchbar

I want to implement a searchbar in my flutter application. I have to go through a listview out of ListTiles. Here I want to check if the title of the listtile contains the letters in the search field. Is this possible with a List?
 It does not have to be with the title. It could be something else with what I can identify the Tile. But please, not the index, the user would not know it. 
Is a List the right widget or do I have to use something else to implement a search Engine in my Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using a 3rd party package, you can use native [`showSearch()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showSearch.html) function :

```
showSearch(context: context, delegate: ListSearchDelegate());
```

And then a class extending [`SearchDelegate`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SearchDelegate-class.html):

```
class ListSearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate{

  ListSearchDelegate({Key key,}): super() ;

  List<String> listItems = <String>['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five'] ;

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {

    return [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: () {
          query = '';
        },
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () {
        close(context, null);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {

    List<String> subList ;

    subList = query != '' ? listItems.where((item) => item.contains(query)).toList() : 
      listItems ;

    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: subList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(subList[index]),
          );
        }
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_search_panel

```
List<SearchItem<int>> data = [
  SearchItem(0, 'This'),
  SearchItem(1, 'is'),
  SearchItem(2, 'a'),
  SearchItem(3, 'test'),
  SearchItem(4, '.'),
];

FlutterSearchPanel<int>(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
  selected: 3,
  title: 'Demo Search Page',
  data: data,
  icon: new Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.white),
  color: Colors.blue,
  textStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0, decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.dotted),
  onChanged: (int value) {
    print(value);
  },
),
```